# Compojure-api removes body-param after the first group of API routes

Tags: clojure, compojure, luminus, compojure-api

I am currently using the [Luminus](http://www.luminusweb.net/) template with the +swagger option, which adds compojure-api support.

My current setup is like so (only relevant bits):

```
(ns my-project.routes.services
  (:require [compojure.api.sweet :refer :all]
            ,,,)

(defapi service-routes
  (POST "/login" req
    :return Result
    :body [user UserLogin]
    :summary "Log the user in"
    (auth/login! req user))

(defapi restricted-service-routes
  (POST "/login2" req
    :return Result
    :body [user UserLogin]
    :summary "Log the user in"
    (auth/login! req user)))
```

and

```
 (ns my-project.handler)
   (:require [my-project.routes.services :refer :all])

 (defroutes app-routes
     #'service-routes
     #'restricted-service-routes)
```

When the server receives the request, it is passed to `app-routes`.
I then used the Swagger UI to test these routes, and the `"/login"` route worked 
fine. However, the completely similar `"/login2"` returns

```
{
  "errors": "(not (map? nil))"
}
```

When I switch the order of the two service groups, the result is as expected: the first route works fine, while the second will not receive the `body`.

Is this a bug with Compojure-api itself? And is there anything I can do to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defapi` macro seems to wrap all the routes to `api-middleware` (check out [compojure-api source code](https://github.com/metosin/compojure-api/blob/59b5d2271ac952ee6a7d3bad484f4e1510b18a59/src/compojure/api/api.clj)) which includes `wrap-params` middleware.
In your setup, you are chaining two set of routes both wrapped in the `api-middleware` and thus calling the `wrap-params` middleware on a request in case of the second `defapi` route (/login2) twice. The first call of `wrap-params` resolves the params correctly but the second `wrap-params` call has nothing to process and thus your code ends up with runtime error.

To solve your issue, try to disable default wrapping by `api-middleware` for all your `defapi` usages but one. See the `:disable-api-middleware` option in the link above.